# Does 10GBASE-R fully replace 10GBASE-X?

Tags: fpga, ethernet, networking, 10gbase

10GBASE-R using 64b/66b encoding scheme (3% overhead)
10GBASE-X using 8b/10b encoding scheme (20% overhead)

10GBASE-R is achieved with single xcvr lane
10GBASE-X is achieved with 4 XAUI xcvr lanes & 2 RXAUI lanes.

Looking at the advantages 10GBASE-R having today, is 10GBASE-X is still being used in today Ethernet world? Or it is just a legacy protocol?

Comment: Just from the encoding schemes, I would assume that 10GBASE-R is less fault-tolerant than 10GBASE-X, since the more bits you have in your line code the more error detection and error correction you can do. But I don't have much background in these things, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it still being used today? Not a valid EE question.

Comment: This type of encoding is not FEC, it does not correct bit errors.

Answer (score 2):

10GBASE-X is essentially obsolete. Four times the pins, four times the fibers or wavelengths, four times the traces, larger transceivers, etc. vs. 10GBASE-R. And no advantage besides lower per-lane bandwidth.

Now, there will be legacy hardware running this protocol, but only because nobody has bothered to replace it with something more modern.